# Registry "forgetting" values

Tags: delphi, windows-7, registry, antivirus

My software stores some values in HKCU\Software\mysoftware which has never been a problem. However, I now also store some values in HKCU\Software\mysoftware\Licenses - ie a subdirectory of the existing data. However, 24 hours later those values simply disappear.

I put logging in my software to check it wasn't deleting the keys and there are no log entries, which is quite expected as the software isn't even running. Somebody suggested using process viewer (from Microsoft) which can trace registry events: however, that gave up working (too many events, even though I'm only watching HKCU\Software\mysoftware registry events) so I'm still no closer to finding *what* is deleting those keys!

I use Avast! anti-virus which somebody else suggested could be a culprit. The actual keys are of the form REG_SZ with "[keyname]=[base64string]". Nothing fancy, around 150 characters. A few hours after the software is closed I can use registry editor to see those values. But sometime later, they're gone! I rarely reboot.

So what else could be deleting the keys?

**UPDATE**

Here's the Delphi 6 code:

```
procedure XXX;
var
    registry : TRegistry;
    code : string;
begin
    try
        registry := TRegistry.Create;
        if registry.OpenKey(REGISTRY_ROOT, true) then begin
            code := [...a base64 string, around 150 chars on average...];
            registry.WriteString(simname, code);
        end;
    finally
        FreeAndNil(registry);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: What compiler are you using, and how did you access the subkey? Are you sure you're not creating/opening the subkey using volatile option?

Comment: Delphi 6 is the environment. I'll paste the code in the original question above.

Comment: Does the Avast! log show anything about eradicating a threat in the timeframe that the value was removed?  Is Avast! scanning daily?  Can you write the value to the registry, manually run the Avast! scan and observe the reg value disappear?

Comment: Avast shows 3: "web & network objects were found infected and blocked" and zero for other categories for the last 30 days. Even if all the registry entries were classed as one "hit" then there would still be 20+ for the last month. But I will try a manual scan now.

Comment: When using SysInternal's Process Monitor, make sure you set the filtering options a bit more aggressively. Instead of just filtering for your Registry key, also filter for `RegDelete...` operations as well. Can't delete what does not exist, right? So you should only get log messages of attempts to delete your key and values, nothing else.

Comment: It makes sense, though there aren't that many events relating to "my" registry keys. Annoyingly the process viewer crashed again last night. I've asked several users of my software and none have this problem, and it doesn't happen on my netbook, so it's something very peculiar to this machine (I'm running Win7 Home Premium).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no closer to finding a solution; however, all I can think of (suggested elsewhere) is that it's the anti-virus confining the application to a sandbox, though there's no notification of such.

Comment: Another reason I don't run anti virus software on my development machine!